# Installing msstats software in Mac OS X. make command not working

Tags: macos, installation

I am trying to install the msstats software in my MacbookPro Yosemite 10.10.5 :

https://github.com/molpopgen/msstats

I follow the instructions and write:  ./configure

```
Lucass-MacBook-Pro:msstats-master lucas$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
/Users/lucas/Dropbox/puc/Softwares/msstats-master/missing: Unknown `-- 
is-lightweight' option
Try `/Users/lucas/Dropbox/puc/Softwares/msstats-master/missing --help' 
for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features by default... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=c++11... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for main in -lgslcblas... no
GSL BLAS runtime library not found
```

Then I write "make" and I get this message:

```
Lucass-MacBook-Pro:msstats-master lucas$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Similarly, with "sudo make install" I get:

```
Lucass-MacBook-Pro:msstats-master lucas$ sudo make install
Password:
make: Nothing to be done for `install'.
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: Your ./configure command ended with an error, you need to fix that error   first (and any others) before you can run make.

Comment: Thank you @JoakimDanielson, may I ask you in which part of the code  you see that there is an error?

Comment: Last line of the output `GSL BLAS runtime library not found`